# WPF ContextMenu IsChecked Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu

How to write Binding for "IsChecked" ?
I want to check either of 2 menu.

If I click "Hello1", I want to add check on "Hello1", 
and remove Check of "Hello2".

If I click "Hello2", I want to add check on "Hello2", 
and remove Check of "Hello1".

I tried for 1 week. but I can not. Please help me "How to write binding" 
There is no example for internet. 
I recently started WPF programming. I only can do form application.
it is very big different....

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenuMain" x:Key="menuListBox">
            <MenuItem Header="Hello1" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheck1, Mode=OneWay}"  Name="ContextMenu_Hello1" Click="ContextMenuClick_Hello1"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Hello2"   IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheck2, Mode=OneWay}" Name="ContextMenu_Hello2" Click="ContextMenuClick_Hello2"/>
    </ContextMenu>
    </Window.Resources>

</Window>
```

My most difficult point is below code.
I tried to use name of "ContextMenu_Hello1" in MainWindow.
but C# does not allow me to use it...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ContextMenu_Hello1.DataContext  // error !
        }
    }
```

Is this out of scope ? but Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `ContextMenu` property of the window. You should also set the `IsCheckable` property to `true` if you want to be able to check the menu items. Also, you cannot set the binding mode to `OneWay`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu Name="ContextMenuMain">
            <MenuItem Header="Hello1" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheck1}"  Name="ContextMenu_Hello1" />
            <MenuItem Header="Hello2" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCheck2}" Name="ContextMenu_Hello2" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Window.ContextMenu>
</Window>
```

When you have made these changes, you can then bind to any property of the `DataContext`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private bool _isCheck1;
    public bool IsCheck1
    {
        get { return _isCheck1; }
        set
        {
            _isCheck1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            _isCheck2 = !_isCheck1;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheck2");
        }
    }

    private bool _isCheck2;
    public bool IsCheck2
    {
        get { return _isCheck2; }
        set
        {
            _isCheck2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            _isCheck1 = !_isCheck2;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCheck1");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```